# Viewer Tutorial Returns AxiosError 500

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

After completing the [Data & Deliverables](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/data) section of the **Simple Viewer Tutorial** I get the message below whenever I go to the http://localhost:8080/api/models url in the browser to test it.

```
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500
```

The Debug console in Visual Studio shows:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd start

simple-viewer@1.0.0 start
node server.js

Server listening on port 8080...
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500
```

I triple checked the code matches the tutorial and I've setup my app credentials and ACC integrations correctly. What else should I do to fix this error?

Comment: I think the issue is because I can't create buckets. Is there a way I can test if I can make a bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out (sort of). I deleted my first app and created a new one. This seemed to fix it. My "Simple Viewer" is working as expected.